# What's the best approach to make PRNGs favourably deterministic a.k.a. biased and how to protect yourself against this?

Tags: randomness

I mean this has certainly been implemented by some scummy PRNG developers, which thought of the economics behind it (especially in the casino and similar businesses). So it might be even legal in some cases, but this not Law StackExchange ;-)

Yes, I am aware that PRNG have a period and hence are practically deterministic already.

My questions would be:

- How do you make a certain PRNG (in two scenarios - black box and the opposite of it) favour certain amount of values? For example, in a casino game how do you make randomness biased for your own benefit?
- And most important, how do you test that your or someone else's PRNG is not biased like this? What if you in theory made such a system that only starts showing it's true intentions after too computationally heavy amount of computations?
- Has there been any real world case studies of this?

Comment: A simple search for [create biased rng](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+biased+rng) gets as first hit for me [Biased Random Number Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2775578/3081018) - which looks like a good fit and goes also into the theory in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2775625/3081018): *"What you are describing is the implementation of a random number generator that draws from a particular probability distribution. ..."*. I.e. it is not the RNG itself which is biased but the distribution it draws from (bias added on top).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I see. Could the cybersecurity related aspects be still salvaged from this question? Especially the detection of such biased distributions, since it's not a pure crypto question(?). Please correct me if I'm wrong though

Comment: The theories behind good random generators, detecting bias etc is considered a part of cryptography, since  good random is essential for good cryptography (biased random in creation of keys can be used to attack encryption, signatures ...). So again, try [crypto.se]. The use case you offered about casino on the other hand is neither a topic of cryptography nor information security - try [math.se].

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I posted on `Cryptography`, could you elaborate what part/parts of the question would be suitable for the `Mathematics` StackExchange? Would it only be use cases in Casinos or use cases in general in the real world?

Comment: If you are interested in creating RNG with a particular bias, then [math.se] is probably best. If you are interested in detecting a biased RNG in the context of cryptography then [crypto.se] is probably best. If there are constraints like a limited number of drawings to detect that a bias exists or to detect a bias as early as possible in order to take advantage of it like in case of casino, then [math.se] is probably best because this targets probability theory. The theory behind all of this is same or similar but the focus is different.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am interested in both viewpoints, but mainly in the detection of biased RNG, because that's the more practical viewpoint, creation is purely theoretical. So my post on `Cryptography` was correct imho. Thank you again for your input, appreciate it ^^